# Linux syntax for if in command line

Tags: shell, centos

What is wrong with this cmd line (Centos 7):

```
if (grep ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/platform.conf)
then echo $(grep ssl_certc /etc/nginx/conf.d/file.conf) > /etc/nginx/conf.d/file-certs.conf
fi
```

In file.conf there are 2 lines  with ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key.
It should move existing SSL certificates from /etc/nginx/conf.d/file.conf to /etc/nginx/conf.d/file-certs.conf.

Comment: `if` is not a Linux statement, it is a shell statement.

Comment: I've never used `if` in command line - got this from official documents (supposed to be written (command) and tested by Linux experts.

Comment: @Kiwy It _also_ returns true/false.

Comment: What official documents did you get this from?

Comment: The syntax of "if" statement changes according to which shell you are using. Check if the shell you are using is the same used in the documentation.

Comment: Besides the fact that most of us couldn't reliably type it without errors?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams of course if you go back to unix, `if` was a command, e.g. https://etsh.io/history/ has links to the manual page and source code.

Comment: If you want to match `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` why are you grepping for `ssl_certc`?

Comment: p.s. People mention the shell because `if` is a shell command, so its syntax depends on which shell you are using, and you didn't say which. But that's probably not important, as the _syntax_ of the `if` statement doesn't seem to be what you were asking about.

Answer (score 19):

There is nothing *syntactically* wrong with the code fragment, but it is unusual.

To test whether a string is found in a file using `grep`, and do something if that is the case, use

```
if grep -qwF ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/platform.conf; then
```

The options `-q`, `-w` and `-F` will make `grep` quiet (`-q`) and will match the given pattern as a fixed string rather than as a regular expression (`-F`).  Furthermore, `-w` will make `grep` look for a complete *word*.  In this case, the string `ssl_certificate3` would *not* match the pattern.

`grep` will return a zero exit status if the string was found in the file, and the body of the `if` statement would be executed.

The statement

```
echo $(somecommand)
```

is a bit useless.

The command substitution `$(somecommand)` will be replaced by the output of `somecommand` and the shell will perform word splitting and filename generation on the resulting string (which is likely unwanted).  Using this with `echo` is useless in the sense that you could just have done

```
somecommand
```

The complete `if` statement:

```
if grep -qwF ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/platform.conf; then
    grep -wF ssl_certc /etc/nginx/conf.d/file.conf >/etc/nginx/conf.d/file-certs.conf
fi
```

(This assumes that `ssl_certc` is a complete word. Remove `-w` from that `grep` otherwise)

Alternatively, using short circuit syntax,

```
grep -qwF ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/platform.conf &&
grep  -wF ssl_certc /etc/nginx/conf.d/file.conf >/etc/nginx/conf.d/file-certs.conf
```

Note that this will *overwrite* the contents of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/file-certs.conf` if that file exists.  Change `>` to `>>` to *append* to the file instead, if overwriting is not intended.

Comment: `echo $(command)` is not exactly the same as `command`, The output is processed, so there is word splitting and glob expansion - both of which are probably unwanted! Good commands to try are `echo $(ls -l)` and `echo $(echo '*')` in directories with files in them.

Comment: @icarus I've now mentioned what happens there a bit more carefully. I never said that the two commands (with `echo` and command substitution/without) were equivalent, as they obviously aren't. Some `echo` implementation will additionally interpret escape sequences. The point of the section is that the whole construct is unneeded.